# Error When I try to get an file on FTP by Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

Environment:

Ftp: Centos6.5 + vsftp

Client: Windows7 64

Error: `"Error while downloading Could not get file size."`

Error code: `ContentNotFoundError 203`

When i try to get an file on FTP, got that error info. But when i used Windows7 + IIS as Ftp server
. The file was downloaded successful,.

Here is the Qt code:

```
    QUrl ftpInfo;
    ftpInfo.setScheme("ftp");
    ftpInfo.setHost("192.168.1.170");
    ftpInfo.setPath("/test.txt");
    ftpInfo.setPort(21);
    ftpInfo.setPassword("123");
    ftpInfo.setUserName("123");
    QNetworkRequest ftpRequest;
    ftpRequest.setUrl(ftpInfo);
    ftpReply = ftp->get(ftpRequest);
    connect(ftp, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(readReply(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(ftpReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

Comment: And i can access Ftp server either Linux or Windows by Browser

Comment: Try to call `ftpReply = ftp->get(ftpRequest);` after you establish signals' connections.

Comment: Try to remove the first slash from the path: `ftpInfo.setPath("test.txt")` or set root path by : `ftpInfo.setPath("//test.txt");`

Comment: Thanks, But still not work got same error. And cant remove setPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
ftpInfo.setPath("/test.txt"); //For Linux Ftp not not work, But IIS Ftp no problem.

ftpInfo.setPath("test.txt"); //Both work fine.
```